# Can't access keras model's weight with tensorflow's build error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**The log was like follow:**

```
2020-09-07 11:45:04.832269: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
sh: sysctl: command not found
2020-09-07 11:45:04.846325: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fcb246816b0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-09-07 11:45:04.846341: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
```

I installed TensorFlow with pip install TensorFlow
I will explain the problem with the example from the official site
**Code:**

```
initial_model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(250, 250, 3)),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 5, strides=2, activation="relu"),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu"),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu"),
    ]
)

feature_extractor = keras.Model(
    inputs=initial_model.inputs,
    outputs=[layer.output for layer in initial_model.layers],
)

# Call feature extractor on test input.
x = tf.ones((1, 250, 250, 3))
features = feature_extractor(x)
```

Then the above error showed, my question is:

How to complier TensorFlow with another flag? And with what kind of flag can I solve this problem?

Comment: Those are not error messages, just informative ones.

Comment: sh: sysctl: command not found, I thought this is a bug when I saw this.....